# Using map in the function is mutating the main array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

I'm new to JS and trying to use map array.prototype.map() function in my code. I need to add one property to the array's each element without changing the main object structure. I have this array of objects

```
const nav = [
  {
    name: 'Home',
    title: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'home',
  },
  {
    name: 'About',
    icon: 'layout-auto',
    title: 'About',
  },
  {
    name: 'Applications',
    icon: 'applications',
    title: 'Applications',
  },
];
```

after mapping through this array it also chaging main nav array's objects.

```
const mappedNav = (arr) => {
  let newArr = arr.map(nav => {
    nav.title = 'test';
    return element;
  });
}

mapNav(nav);

console.table(nav);
```

How can I add properties to the new array's objects wihout mutating them?

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to do. You say you don't want to modify `nav` but then you say you need to add a property to each of its elements. `map` returns a new array.

Comment: I mean I need to add one new property to the newArr without mutating main nav array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`). Using spread inside of an object literal will copy the (own enumerable) keys of the object into the newly created object literal (`{}`). This way you're mapping each object to a new object, which has the same keys and values as the current object, along with an overwritten/new `title` attribute.

```js
const nav = [ { name: 'Home', title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'home', }, { name: 'About', icon: 'layout-auto', title: 'About', }, { name: 'Applications', icon: 'applications', title: 'Applications', } ];

const res = nav.map(obj => {
  return {...obj, title: "test"};
});
console.log(res);
```

Note that object spread is ES9, if you want ES6, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead, which will merge the properties of one (or more) objects into each other.

```js
const nav = [ { name: 'Home', title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'home', }, { name: 'About', icon: 'layout-auto', title: 'About', }, { name: 'Applications', icon: 'applications', title: 'Applications', } ];

const res = nav.map(obj => {
  return Object.assign({}, obj, {title: "test"});
// merge -------------(1^)-(2^)--(3^)
// (1) - the new object to return (used to make a shallow copy)
// (2) - merge obj (2) into (1)
// (3) - merge keys from {title: "test"} into the result of (2) above 
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

map() function with spread operator can achieve this.

```js
    const nav = [
      {
        name: 'Home',
        title: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'home',
      },
      {
        name: 'About',
        icon: 'layout-auto',
        title: 'About',
      },
      {
        name: 'Applications',
        icon: 'applications',
        title: 'Applications',
      },
    ].map(v => ({...v, title: "test"}));
    
    console.log(nav)
```